# Explicit function for $x$ and $y$ with $(u+iv)^{2}=x+iy$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $x + iy \in \mathbb{C}$, $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$. Determine   $x$ and $y$ that explicitly as a function of  variables $u, v \in \mathbb{R}$ with $(u + iv)^{2}=x + iy$.

I have no idea how to do this - I thought you had to split it into real and imaginary parts. Now I am thinking it has something to do with Cauchy Riemann equations?

Comment: Yes split it into real and imaginary parts, no has nothing to do with cauchy riemann, see answers for more details

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$(u+iv)^2 = u^2+2iuv-v^2 = (u^2-v^2) + i(2uv)$$

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x,y)  = (u^2-v^2) + 2uvi$$